# MySQL: Insert if doesnt exist else Insert again

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database table that uses a 32 character string as a ID, so when I add new data to the table the query generates the string ID and inserts the data to the table. The problem is that the query could generate a repeated ID, so what I did is use `IGNORE` to not insert if the ID exists

Here's the code:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO contacts (id_contacts, user_id, contact_id, confirmed ) 
values ((substring(MD5(UUID()), -32)),1,2,0)
```

How can I repeat the query until the ID does not exist and it inserts the data?

Comment: Handle the (extremely rare) PK violation in code/programmatically.

Comment: Bear in mind that there is a significant performance payoff when using alphanumeric IDs instead of numeric ones when you have large data sets.

Comment: @user2864740 Are you saying that there is no need for prevention?

Comment: What purpose does the MD5 serve?  Why not just use a number or UUID?  The answer to that determines the best solution.

Comment: @I'mnothuman The output domains are so large that the chance of collision are very small - a V4 (Random) UUID from the _same generator_ is effectively "guaranteed unique"; the MD5 softens this although the space remains huge (still 128 bits!); also MD5 result is 32 chars.. A violation is definitely an exceptional case - maybe even 'failing' (assuming adequate logging) is an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to change your query just create a unique index on id_contacts column, something like

`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_id_contacts 
ON contacts (id_contacts);`

Answer (score -1):

This is a bit long for a comment.

If you need a unique id that doesn't repeat, then . . . `auto_increment` comes to mind:

```
create table contacts (
    contact_id int auto_increment primary key,
    . . .
```

If you really want a uuid in the column, then define it separately and declare it to be unique.  Of course, then you will have to deal with uniqueness violations on that column.

Comment: No difference in handling a uniqueness violation which is the core 'problem'.

Comment: The point appeared to be "I don't care what the problem / design choice is, use an auto increment field (my words) .. then you will [still] have to deal with uniqueness violations on that column] (not my words)."

Comment: @user2864740 . . . An auto-increment column should not have duplicate issues.

Comment: The problem isn't about inserting rows. The problem is about inserting rows with a given UNIQUE CONSTRAINT / key and supposed violation (in this case that's ultimately from a GUID which also opens up other discussion). While there is indeed an argument, for consistency and physical fragmentation (especially compared to the MD5 of a GUID..), using a surrogate auto-increment PK this is a separate conversation from the asked question. Presumably there is a need for said unique key and answers should acknowledge this proposed/perceived need for a key.